# StageText multiline problems

Tags: actionscript-3

So I am pretty new to this whole AIR for iOS development thing and am just dipping my toe into the StageText object for a project I am working on. I am having trouble getting my StageText to be restricted to a single line. (such as for username input)

The documentation is terrible from Adobe but blog posts I have found have said to pass "false" to the StageTextInitOptions which seems to sorta work, but not really. When I do this the read-only multiline property on the stageText option traces as "false" which is good but when I actually type in the field it still breaks and goes to the next line when it is full.

here is my code:

```
        var stageTextInitOptions = new StageTextInitOptions(false);
        stageText = new StageText(stageTextInitOptions);
        stageText.stage = stage;        
        stageText.viewPort = new Rectangle(0, 0, w, h);

        trace(stageText.multiline); //traces out as false
```

EDIT: The problem seems to be in desktop only, when the app is placed on an ipad the multiline limitation functions as expected. (The problem is it NEEDS to work on both desktop and ios)

Any ideas? thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

StageText uses native mobile keyboards only on iOs and Android. You will need to work with the TextField and wordwrapping on the Desktop.

Why would you not use a regular hardware keyboard on a Desktop though? It's as native for Desktops as it gets.

Answer (score 0):

use :

```
var stageTextInitOptions = new StageTextInitOptions(true);
```

Comment: Please format your source code and add some explanations why it fixes the problem.

Comment: I get an error: `Call to a possibly undefined method StageTextInitOptions.`